# What is the difference between a foramen and a fissure?

Tags: bones

From my understanding, a foramen is a round opening inside a bone, whilst a fissure is a slightly longer opening? What exactly qualifies a fissure as a fissure and not a foramen? Why is the superior orbital fissue not a foramen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right, the difference is in the shape.

According to [dictionary](https://dictionary.com), a **fissure** is:

> 1. A narrow opening produced by cleavage or separation of parts.
> 2. ...
> 3. Anatomy. A natural division or groove in an organ, as in the brain.

Whilst a **foramen** usually describes a (somewhat) round "hole".